# Google Maps - SVG marker cut off

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, svg, google-maps-api-3

Why my svg icons for google.maps.Marker are cut off? 
I tried many of combinations with size and scaledSize...

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng({lat: el.lat, lng: el.lon}),
            icon: {
                url: "/images/icons/observation_" + el.rate + ".svg",
                size: new google.maps.Size(20, 20),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 10),
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 20)
            },
            zIndex: 6,
            map: map.map
        });
```

Svg icons should by 20x20 px.

https://jsfiddle.net/d3v5huzr/

Here is preview:
[image: Google Maps SVG markers]

Comment: add working code in  fiddle

Comment: @Deep3015 Added fiddle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to set width and height attributes of the svg element like this:

```
<svg height="40px" width="40px" ... >
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zvtnohyv/

Comment: This! Been searching for a solution for ages and this is the only answer which fixes it.

Comment: Has this fiddle been manipulated? That code is nowhere to be found on that fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You can use  `zoom_changed` from  [events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events)  and add event Listener, for refreshing  the marker icon on zoom

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3up06auj/)

Code below

```
var map;

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {
    lat: -34.397,
    lng: 150.644
  },
  zoom: 8
});
var icon = {
  url: "http://svgshare.com/i/1jz.svg",
}
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng({
    lat: -34.397,
    lng: 150.644
  }),
  icon: icon,
  /*icon: {
    url: "http://svgshare.com/i/1jz.svg",
    // size: new google.maps.Size(20, 20),
    // origin: new google.maps.Point(5, 5),
    // anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 10),
    // scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(20, 20)
  },*/
  zIndex: 6,
  map: map
});
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
  marker.setIcon(icon);
});
```

Comment: Nothing change, icon still is cut off.

Comment: For me still cut off http://imgur.com/a/USAhd (in Chrome), in Firefox doesn't even show svg oO

Comment: exactly same code are you using note `var icon = {
  url: "http://svgshare.com/i/1jz.svg",
}`  will be outside

Comment: Can you show me screenshot of your? Because icon is circle and i have 1/4 of it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145529/discussion-between-deep-3015-and-sko).